# Cisco Prime Infrastructure 2.0 : IP Type - Not Detected

Tags: cisco, ipv4, snmp

I have a Cisco Prime Infrastructure server which has fully discovered all my devices on my network.

But when I go to the "Clients & Users" tab (the new name of the old "User Tracking" feature), a lot of information is missing. 
All the clients are correctly discovered by their MAC Address (my switches are configured with MAC notification traps) but their IP addresses/Hostnames are not pulled.

The only devices that push IP address information are 2960X (newish), so I am thinking that maybe the Prime Infrastructure does not poll correctly the MIB on my old devices (3750s & 2950s) but polls correctly the more "recent" MIB of the 2960X...

Has anyone encountered the same issue ? Any workarounds ?

Thanks

Jeremy

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

For those interested : the problem was resolved by migrating the core network from an old C6006 to a brand-new Catalyst 6807XL.
I guess the polling of ARP information was failing on the old cores. Since migrating every IP for every client has been pulled up, without changing anything to the Prime Infrastructure config.

HTH

Jeremy